# Удаление переменных в PHP

Tags: php

Нужно ли в коде удалять все используемые переменные в конце? 
Например:

```
$test = date("d.m.Y");
echo $test;
unset($test); // Нужна ли эта строка?
```

Comment: Похоже на Paranoid Style Coding :) В PHP же есть Garbage Collector, можно уж тогда его запускать.

Comment: @Shamanis: "Похоже на Paranoid Style Coding"
Да, есть немного) Garbage Collector - запускаешь его в начале, после в конце запускаешь gc_disable() и весь мусор удаляется? Но нужно ли это? Наверно это нужно скорее для PHP win32 оконных приложенй, чтобы оперативку не зассорять?

Comment: PHP win32 оконных приложенй? хв

Comment: Ну да, по-мему PHP GUI называется. Ни разу не делал для винды приложений на php?

Comment: Судя по примеру вопрос из раздела теоретичесих, соответственно есть неплохая статья на эту тему: [Работа с памятью (и всё же она есть)][1]

  [1]:http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/134784/

Comment: Спасибо, хабрхабр - чёткий блог)

Comment: *facepalm*

Comment: Я что-то только сейчас догнал, вы имеете в виду нужно ли в конце работы скрипта удалять переменные? - нет, не нужно, PHP сам подчистит память. Хотя есть некоторые вещи которые обязательно или желательно делать нужно : закрывать дескриптор файла(файловый указатель вроде) открытый функцией fopen иначе файл заблокируется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все зависит от того, что вы делаете дальше и делали до этого. Если создается простенький объект (или переменная) - то смысл ее уничтожать? Сборщик мусора сделает все сам. Если же создаете объемный объект сейчас и далее планируете также что-то громоздкое создавать (например в цикле) и при этом боитесь, что память ваша станет девичьей (девушки извините, сам этим страдаю), то тогда можно и сборщик вызвать.
Подробнее можешь про деструкторы прочитать. Пишут о них мало, т.к. они редко используются, но вдруг это именно тот случай?))

Answer (score 2):

Еще, если эта переменная используется в каком-то участке кода, который представляет из себя  отдельный логический блок, этот блок можно оформить в виде функции со своими локальными переменными.

Когда функция отработает, все ее локальные переменные освободят память.

Answer (score 2):

Чистить нужно только в том случае, если переменная объёмом содержащейся в ней информации превышает 100кб и более, хотя тут уже на ваш выбор, я же из личного опыта. Бывает так, что во время исполнения скрипт может кушать и 300кб, а то и по 2мб.
А вот ваш код можно упростить :

```
echo date("d.m.Y");
```

Если полученная дата больше нигде не понадобится.

Comment: Спасибо, "А вот ваш код можно упростить :" - КЭП =)

Comment: Рад стараться))

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно.

Comment: @Elime, Поясните свой ответ.

Comment: @Expert, Нет необходимости в освобождении памяти переменной, php сам освобождает память.

Если переменная передается через глобальные массивы то имеет смысл ее убить.

Удалять переменные ради скорости скрипта - это байтодрочерство, которым не стоит забивать себе голову. ИМХО.